# Does $\xi_{ni}\overset{p}\to0$ imply $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_{ni}\overset{p}\to0?$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Suppose for each $i=1,\cdots,n$, we have 
$$\xi_{ni}\overset{p}\to0.$$
Can we claim that
$$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_{ni}\overset{p}\to0?$$

Here $\overset{p}\to$ means convergence in probability. That is, for any $\varepsilon>0$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|\xi_{ni}|>\varepsilon)=0$

Comment: What if $\xi_{n,i} = i/n$? Then $\xi_{n,i} \stackrel{p}{\to} 0 $ as $n\to\infty$ for each $i$, but $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \xi_{n,i} = \frac{n+1}{2} \stackrel{p}{\to} \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: OP is saying that$\xi_{ni} \to 0$ for $i \leq n$ and this is a bit confusing. Apparently he wants to allow $i$ to depend on $n$. In this example $\xi_{n,n}$ does not tend to $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, That's a fair point. Thank you for bringing that subtlety to my notice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You deleted a similar question where there was only one subscript.  But anyway, the result is false.

Let $\xi_{n,i}=n 1_{[\frac{i-1}n,\frac{i}n)}$ be a sequence of random variables on the usual $[0,1)$.  Then for each $i$ (we can even allow it to depend on $n$), $\xi_{n,i}\xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}}_n0$ because $\mathbb{P}(\xi_{n,i}>\varepsilon)=\frac1n$ as long as $\varepsilon$ is small.  However, $n^{-1}\sum_i\xi_{n,i}=1$.  You can give more extreme examples.

This also gives a counterexample to your previous question --- if $\xi_n\xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}}_n0$, the Cesaro sums need not converge to 0 in probability --- just lay these $\xi_{n,i}$ out like 
$$\xi_{1,1},\xi_{2,1},\xi_{2,2},\xi_{3,1},\xi_{3,2},\xi_{3,3},\dots,\xi_{n,1},\dots,\xi_{n,n},\dots$$
and note the Cesaro limit has to be the constant function 1.